# In Bookdown, `\textcolor` is not recognized when I attempt to compile an epub book using Pandoc

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, tex, bookdown

In bookdown, it appears that `\textcolor` in latex is not recognized when I try to compile using

`bookdown::render_book('bookdown::epub_book')`

even though I have added `\usepackage{xcolor}` into the preamble.tex file.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the way the document is processed. I will leave out processing by the knitr and R Markdown packages and focus on pandoc, which is the final step when converting from Markdown to any other format.

Pandoc first parses the document into an internal, intermediate format. We can inspect that format by choosing `native` as the target format. So when we feed `\textcolor{red}{Mars}` to pandoc, it will show us the native representation:

```
$ printf '\\textcolor{red}{Mars}' | pandoc --from=markdown --to=native
[Para [RawInline (Format "tex") "\\textcolor{red}{Mars}"]]
```

What this means is that, without going into too much detail, pandoc recognizes `\textcolor...` as a raw LaTeX command embedded into Markdown. It does not try to parse the LaTeX any further, as it was told to read Markdown, not LaTeX. This raw LaTeX snippet will be included in the output when producing output of a format which supports inclusion of LaTeX. The snippet is left out by pandoc when generating HTML/EPUB, as including it would not have the intended effect.

So can we convince pandoc to continue parsing, and does pandoc know how to translate `\textcolor` from LaTeX to HTML?

The second question is easy to answer by converting the LaTeX to HTML via pandoc:

```
$ printf '\\textcolor{red}{Mars}' | pandoc --from=latex --to=html
<p><span style="color: red">Mars</span></p>
```

That looks good, so let's make pandoc parse the raw LaTeX snippets as the next step. Pandoc has a feature called [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) which allow us to modify the internal document representation programmatically. Here is such a filter which will parse the raw LaTeX commands:

```lua
function RawInline (el)
  if el.format == 'tex' then
    local blocks = pandoc.read(el.text, 'latex').blocks
    return blocks[1] and blocks[1].content or el
  end
end
```

Save this code to a file `parse-latex.lua` and make your document processing pipeline use this file:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::epub_book:
    pandoc_args: ['--lua-filter=/path/to/your/parse-latex.lua']
---
```

The colored text should now show up in your epub book.

Comment: Thank you! This is simply amazing, efficient and hard hitting! Definitely appreciate the help here.

Comment: Just a quick followup, the code ran well on my computer, on a server I got an `"attempt to index a nil value (field '?')"` error. I believe one of the fields might be nil. I tried to change the if statement to `if el.format and el.format == 'tex' and el.text then` but still got the error. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks very much again!

Comment: Yikes. I think what happend is that a LaTeX snippet, e.g. `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}`, didn't produce any output after parsing. I have adjusted the filter to stop it from failing in that case.