# Defining custom Markdown syntax in RMarkdown / pander

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

In Markdown / RMarkdown, **this** is translated to **bold**, _this_ is *cursive* etc.

Is it possible to create a custom syntax? For example, that -this- (a word between two dashes) gets translated to something I define myself (via css for html and latex for pdf)?

Comment: Both `pander` and general R Markdown relies on `pandoc` ... which defines the syntax, so I don't think so: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html -- on the other hand, you can provide your own stylesheet etc to pandoc, so there are some flexibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Document parsing is done by [pandoc](https://pandoc.org). For this kind of customization, one would have to customize pandoc's Markdown reader (written in Haskell), and then use the self-compiled binary for knitting.

One way to get close to having custom elements is to use spans (`[like so]{.example}`) or raw LaTeX (`\foo{text}`) in combination with [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). You can then convert specific spans to any output you like. See, e.g., this answer about how to [support `\textcolor` for HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57552247/2425163).

See also [this beautiful technique](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/DMAa5C3PJ8A/EASRpU0PAQAJ) by John MacFarlane, the author of pandoc.