# Create new emphasis command R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

In R Markdown, to make a text bold, we just need to do:

`**code**`

The the word **code** shows in bold.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a new command, let's say:

`***code***`

That would make the text highlighted?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not, but you could use CSS to change the display of one of the 4 types of emphasis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easily possible to create new markup, but one can change the way existing markup commands are rendered. Text enclosed by three stars is interpreted as ***emphasized strong emphasis***. So one has to change that interpretation and change it to something else. One way to do so is via [pandoc Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). We just have to match on pandoc's internal representation of emphasized strong text and convert it to whatever we want:

```lua
function Strong (strong)
  -- if this contains only one element, and if that element
  -- is emphasized text, convert it to highlighted text.
  local element = #strong.content == 1 and strong.content[1]
  if element and element.t == 'Emph' then
    table.insert(element.content, 1, pandoc.RawInline('html', '<mark>'))
    table.insert(element.content, pandoc.RawInline('html', '</mark>'))
    return element.content
  end
end
```

The above works for HTML output. One would have to define what "highlighted text" means for each targeted format.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57548218/2425163) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58697467/2425163) question for other approaches to the problem, and for details of how to use the filter with R Markdown.